# How to re-join a group/room after login using smack 4.1

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, chatroom

**This is what i am doing:-**
Trying to join a group after login.

connection.login(userDate.getUserId(), userDate.getUserPassword());

****after login ****

```
 String groupName =
            XmppUtils.buildMUCName(results.get(i).getGroupName().trim());
                            MultiUserChat multiUserChat = managerMuc.getMultiUserChat(groupName);
                            try {

                                if (!multiUserChat.isJoined()) {
                                    multiUserChat.join(userId);
                                } } catch (SmackException.NoResponseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (XMPPException.XMPPErrorException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (SmackException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

Comment: this issue resolved

Answer (score 1):

```
public void joinMultiUserChatRoom(String userName, String roomName) {
        // Get the MultiUserChatManager
        MultiUserChatManager manager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);

        // Create a MultiUserChat using an XMPPConnection for a room
        MultiUserChat multiUserChat = manager.getMultiUserChat(roomName + "servername");

        DiscussionHistory history = new DiscussionHistory();
        history.setMaxStanzas(-1);
        try {
            multiUserChat.join(userName+"servername`enter code here`",userName, history, connection.getPacketReplyTimeout());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hope it works to rejoining the room for me.Try this.

Comment: How can we join 100+ MUC after relogin?